# Poplulating an serializing a Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, xml-serialization

Was hoping I could ask some help in serializing a dictionary to an Xml file.

I extract data from the database and it appears as follow and want this in an Xml file.

[image]

This is my class(object) that I intend to serialize along with as method to serialize a list as.

```
public class Product
{
    static public void SerializeToXMLCollection(List<Product> products)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Product>));
        string path = string.Concat(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "../../Products.xml");
        TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(path);
        serializer.Serialize(textWriter, products);
        textWriter.Close();
    }

    public Guid guid
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


    public Dictionary<string, List<string>> MyDictionary
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

This is the query along with the list I use to add each Product instance

```
List<Product> products = new List<Product>();

while (dbread.Read())
        {

            Product p = new Product();

            string code = (string)dbread["ProdId"];
            string Subject = (string)dbread["Subject"];
            string GeneralSubject = (string)dbread["GeneralSubject"];
            p.guid = Guid.NewGuid();

            if (dict.ContainsKey(code))
            {
                dict[code].Add(Subject);


            }
            else
            {

                dict.Add(code, new List<string> { Subject, GeneralSubject});

            }
            //I assign the dict object to myDictionary in the Product class
            p.MyDictionary = dict;
            //now I add the entire object to List<Product> products so as to serialize this list   
            products.Add(p);
```

Finally I try to serialize the list

```
Product.SerializeToXMLCollection(products);
```

but I get an InvalidOPerationException.

How can I serialize this object? I think the problem could be that the object contains a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the DataContractSerializer supports Dictionary objects. I even remember using it at some point, but can't seem to find any of my own examples.

There are some examples however on the official docs page here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx

Otherwise, you may need to use a replacement Dictionary class that supports XML serialization, such as http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2006/05/03/444961.aspx